# how to animate keyframes at different speed?

Tags: css, animation

I have five points for the animation keyframes `0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%` and I wanted to make my animation faster in all except from 75% to 100% like this:

```
animation: goal 1s, goal 1s, goal 1s, goal 1s, goal 15s;
```

But animating at same speed of **15s**. And I tried like this:

```
animation: goal 1s, goal 1s, goal 1s, goal 15s, goal 1s;
```

Now it's animating at same speed of **1s**.

So, I cannot get understand I how can have 1s speed from 0% to 75% and 15s from 75% to 100%.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gp59n/)

Answer (score 0):

Either split it to  2 separate animations or use an easing, easeOutExpo or something